# How to create an updating value to Label in JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading

im new to Java and JavaFX and I want to create a GUI with a Label which shows the current system Time.
The Problem is: the Time Value doesn't update. So I wanted to create a Thread, that is updating my Time-Value and also the Label every 1 second with the command:

label_time_show.setText(curTime);

In the inizialize method (see code below) the "label_show_time" can be inizialized with any value, but when I try to setText in an other method I get the following Error:

Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException

I commented the line in the Code where the Label is null and where the Label is NOT null.

Can someone help me with this Problem?

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable, Runnable
{
    public String curTime;  // <--- main value of time (String)


    @FXML
    private Label label_time_show;
    @FXML
    private Label label_time;

    // initializer
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {    
        java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
        Long sysTime = now.getTime();
        String sysTimeString = sysTime.toString();    
        Integer h = now.getHours();
        Integer m = now.getMinutes();
        Integer s = now.getSeconds();
        String hh = h.toString();
        String mm = m.toString();
        String ss = s.toString();
        curTime = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;


        label_show_time.setText(curTime); // <---- label_show_time is NOT null            
    }    

    // run method
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("THREAD FXMLController running....");  
        while(true)
        {        
            time();            
        }        
    }

    public void time()
    {
        java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
        Long sysTime = now.getTime();
        String sysTimeString = sysTime.toString();    
        Integer h = now.getHours();
        Integer m = now.getMinutes();
        Integer s = now.getSeconds();
        String hh = h.toString();
        String mm = m.toString();
        String ss = s.toString();
        curTime = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;

        label_show_time.setText(curTime);   // <---- label_show_time is null !!! throws ERROR
    }       
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that your `run` (and so your `time`) method will be invoked before `label_show_time` is initialized by @FXML.

Comment: For starters, you should be calling `setText` using `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: Also, you're not including a lot of relevant code. How do you start your thread/start your gui. Would it be reasonable to start your thread after you gui has been initialized and displayed? You can do that without using `sleep`

Answer (score 0):

So, given the limited information, I'll take a blind stab at this. At the end of your initialize method your label is not null, so start your thread then.

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{    

    //java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
    //Long sysTime = now.getTime();
    //String sysTimeString = sysTime.toString();    
    //Integer h = now.getHours();
    //Integer m = now.getMinutes();
    //Integer s = now.getSeconds();
    //String hh = h.toString();
    //String mm = m.toString();
    //String ss = s.toString();
    //curTime = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    //label_show_time.setText(curTime); // <---- label_show_time is NOT null 
    //Since the label not null here, start your thread here.
    new Thread(this).start();           
}
```

Then your `time` method would be similar except you would post things to the Platform thread.

```
public void time()
{
    java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
    Long sysTime = now.getTime();
    String sysTimeString = sysTime.toString();    
    Integer h = now.getHours();
    Integer m = now.getMinutes();
    Integer s = now.getSeconds();
    String hh = h.toString();
    String mm = m.toString();
    String ss = s.toString();
    curTime = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    Platform.runLater(()->{
        label_show_time.setText(curTime);
    });
}
```

You might want to put a sleep in your run method since you only need to update every second.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void run(){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    while (true){   
        Date date = new Date();
        label_show_time.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
        try{
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
```

mb it helps you?
and init your label.

update:

```
 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ...
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    Date date = new Date();
                    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
                    try{
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: No :( throws me the same Error again:

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at GUIpackage.FXMLDocumentController.run(FXMLDocumentController.java:67)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: the label will be initialized via @FXML but this happens after the `run` method is invoked

Comment: mb init it directly?

Comment: Then my Time isn't updating, because it is not running in a Thread. I need to constantly upgrade the value and setText() to my Label.

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4